# How is my question opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, specific-question

This question of mine:

[Where have people gone when CouchSurfing became subscriber-only?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/175665/where-have-people-gone-when-couchsurfing-became-subscriber-only)

has been closed as opinion-based. But - it's a factual question and I explicitly said I'm not interested in speculation, but in information. It's not as though this is philosophically or logically unknowable.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

Agreed, example of a factual, non-opinion-based answer: the result of a poll amongst former CouchSurfing users. I voted to re-reopen. You could try posting your question to https://www.reddit.com/r/couchsurfing/ too.

Comment: Didn't think about that, but... won't I just get berated for suggesting the CS is "gone"?

Comment: @einpoklum maybe. QA forums aren't friendly places typically.

Comment: polls are off topic on all SE sites. "Is there a replacement for" type questions might work, but any question that can have a large number of equally-correct answers is off topic on all SE sites. "How can I do this thing I used to be able to do at" is also a possibility but could be both too broad and opinion based. "Is X a suitable replacement for" or "what are the key differences between X and" is starting to get better.

Comment: @KateGregory the answer wouldn't be a poll, but a pointer to a completed poll eg https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/72457/452.

Comment: I agreed with re-opening.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: [Asked the question there](https://www.reddit.com/r/couchsurfing/comments/wq86w3/what_happend_to_the_cs_userbase_after_the_site/), thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @KateGregory: Ah, sorry, ok.